# Changing the base on a vector given a relationship between bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, change-of-basis

I was given the following question (I am taking this course on my own which is why I am lacking a lot of clarity):

> Let $A=${$a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$} and $B=${$b_1,b_2,b_3$} be bases for a vector space $V$ and suppose $b_1=6a_1-6a_3,b_2=-a_1+4a_2,b_3=a_1+a_2+5a_3.$ Find the change of coordinates from $B$ to $A$. Find $[x]_A$ for $x=b_1-4b_2+4b_3$.

I am trying to understand the question so I can solve it and others like it and am looking for some guidance. These are my thoughts: The given $x$ at the end of the question is $x$ in the $B$-basis. So in the $B$-basis it can be written as $\left[\begin{matrix}1\\-4\\4\\\end{matrix}\right]$. We want to convert it to the $A$-basis. The relationship between $A$ and $B$ is given - each of the vectors of $B$ is a linear-combination of the $A$ vectors.

Here is where I'm unsure of what my next step should be. I can set up a system of equations using $[x]_B$ as my solution set - like this: $$6a_1-6a_3=1\\-a_1+4a_2=-4\\a_1+a_2+5a_3=4$$ I can set this up as a matrix: $\left[\begin{matrix}6&0&-6&1\\-1&4&0&-4\\1&1&5&4\\\end{matrix}\right]$ and solve to get my solution. This would make my solution: $[x]_A=\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{14}{15}\\\frac{-23}{20}\\\frac{23}{30}\\\end{matrix}\right]$.

I don't believe this answer is right, and I think I may be attempting this problem in entirely the wrong way. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach looks correct to me though i didnt check if the calculation is correct.

I would anyway try a different aproach. From the equations
$$
b_1=6a_1−6a_3,b_2=−a_1+4a_2,b_3=a_1+a_2+5a_3
$$

we can create a Matrix $M$ which changes the basis from $A$ to $B$. So that we have that $M[x]_A = [x]_B$ This Matrix is:
$$
M = \left(\begin{matrix}6&0&-6\\-1&4&0\\1&1&5 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
We can invert that Matrix and get $M^{-1}$ and then $M^{-1}[x]_B$ changes $[x]_B$ to $[x]_A$.

Comment: This seems much simpler! Would the answer then be [11,-15,-1]? This is not the same as my answer

Comment: I plugged the matrix $M$ into a matrix inverter and then into a matrix multiplicator because i dont like calculating :P. Anyway the result is exactly yours from your question :)

Comment: I took $M^{-1}$ times $[X]_B$ on a TI -NSpire. I got a different result than my original (and different than {11,-15,-1}). When multiplying I really did $[X]_B*M^{-1}$ because it seems to me that it needs to go that way in order to multiply. Is this the reason for the differences? The $x_b$ I am using is {1,-4,4}.

Comment: I just looked at the answer key. They have a different solution ($\left(\begin{matrix}14\\-12\\14\\\end{matrix}\right)$) but they also used a different matrix M. They had the rows as columns and the columns as rows - like this: $\left(\begin{matrix}6&-1&1\\0&4&1\\-6&0&5\\\end{matrix}\right)$.     Are they the ones making a mistake?

Comment: If your vectors are transpose which means $1\times 3$ then you multiply from the right and then you chose the transposed matrix you said.
Anyway the solution should be correct. 14, -12, 14 is wrong since $b1 = 6a_1 - 6a_3 =0$ then, but it should be $1$.

Comment: True! Thank you for your help!